# Next.js trouble with directories

Tags: reactjs, next.js13

I am running the tutorial for Next.js, and the first steps are very simple. Create a new page, and navigate to it after starting up your dev server on localhost:3000.

The new page is in the `src/app` directory, which according to the documentation has recently replaced the `pages` directory, so as far as I can tell, there should be no problem. but when I navigate to http://localhost:3000/posts/first-post I get a 404.

The following is my folder structure:
[image: project folder structure]

Contents of my `jsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

I tried changing the directory of course, moving it in and out the src/app directory, I tried re-starting the dev server, and I have tried changing the contents of the `jsconfig.json` file from

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

To

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/app/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When migrating from `pages` to `app` structure, the naming of the file matters.

In `pages` if you named your file a certain way, it created a route with the name of the file (in your case first-post). With the `app` folder structure, your pages have to been named `page.[txs|jsx|js]` to work.

So if you wanted a page at `/posts/first-post` you would need a structure like

```
app/
├─ pages/
│  ├─ first-post/
│  │  ├─ page.js
```

You can always refer to the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#pages) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, but I didn't migrate this project, I created it from scratch using the npx create-next-app command in the terminal, and I haven't changed the folder structure at all. So the structure in the screenshot is what came out of the box.

Comment: @BrianGrieco No problem! I meant that you were used to have the `page` folder structure before, so `app` makes it a bit different. Basically renaming the `first-post.js` to `page.js` and putting it inside a `first-post` folder should fix your 404 issue

Answer (score 0):

That's because Next is looking for a page.js file and isn't finding any, therefore not making not even the route 'posts' public.
You need to create a new folder "first-post" and inside a page.js file.

Check the documentation [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/defining-routes).

Answer (score 0):

That's simply because, as per [Nextjs Documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing)  :

Each segment requires a page.[tsx,jsx] file. In this case, It is necessary for you to rearrange your files in the following format:

```
app/
├─ posts/
│  ├─ first-post/
│  │  ├─ page.js
```